# Expresso Store "custom order status" message input field - as textarea?

Tags: expresso-store, custom-order-fields

Is there a little modification to Expresso Store 2.5 that I can make that would turn the "custom order status" message input (that appears in the Order Status controls when you click "Edit Status", and displays on email notifications when you use {custom_order_status} ) to a textarea field of some size?

I have a client who often writes longer messages to clients when their order is shipped, and wants to use this field as the space for writing it. It would probably be more effective for this use if she had a textarea field to work with.

If it's more appropriate for them to be using some other method to put custom messages into Store notifications, I'd welcome being steered to that. (I suppose she can also just write the messages separately, if she needs to...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

it's a core hack, but yes. Open **/store/views/orders/show.php** and find line 56. Change:

```
lang('store.message').': '.form_input('message','','width=10%, style=width:50%').BR.BR.
```

To:

```
lang('store.message').': '.form_textarea('message','','width=10%, style=width:50%').BR.BR.
```